# Implementing something like AWS Lambda functions in Apache Ignite

Tags: aws-lambda, ignite

Would it be possible to use Apache Ignite to implement something like AWS Lambda on premise?
In other words, would I be able to use distributed closure in Ignite in a similar way as AWS Lambda?

What about versioning/updating closures at runtime? And what about packaging a closure in a jar with dependencies in it (eg. FatJar/UberJar/ShadowJar) do be distributed to remote nodes?

Comment: I think I found an example https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/misc/deployment/DeploymentExample.java and the documentation for it: https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.5/docs/deployment-spi Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a use case for Compute Grid [1].

You can use task deployment capabilities [2] or P2P class loading [3] for (re)deploying your closures.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/compute-grid

[2] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/deployment-spi

[3] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/zero-deployment